# Am I allowed to create and distribute a deb package to Ubuntu store if I didn't develop the software?

Tags: packaging, official-repositories

Am I allowed to create and distribute a deb package to Ubuntu store if I didn't develop the software?

I want to create a package (.deb) file following Debian/Ubuntu standards, submit it to Ubuntu store and wait for approval.

Must I be the original developer of the software to do so?

The data I want to package is this, a script to install CSF-LFD, an intrusion prevention system based on the Linux IP tables:

```
cd /usr/src
rm -fv csf.tgz
wget https://download.configserver.com/csf.tgz
tar -xzf csf.tgz
cd csf
sh install.sh
sed -i 's/TESTING = "1"/TESTING = "0"/g' /etc/csf/csf.conf
csf -r
perl /usr/local/csf/bin/csftest.pl
```

I would like to package it in such a way that `apt-get install csf-lfd` will do just that.

Comment: [License of CSF](https://download.configserver.com/csf/license.txt) states this:

{the owner} hereby grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable licence to download and use (the "Product") and the accompanying documentation (the 
"Documentation") on the following terms...

which means you are *not* given right to redistribute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vast majority of packages in the Ubuntu repositories are packaged by somebody other than the original developers. What matters is the license under which the software is distributed (which will dictate whether you can even package it in the first place). If you're not selling on the store, then the script must be under a license that permits free redistribution (otherwise you have run into trouble just by posting it here).

The [webupd8 Java PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) packages, for example, are essentially scripts that download and install Java from the Oracle site.